# Can an embassy in a hostile country send people in diplomatic pouches?

Tags: international

Currently, a few notable people (such as Julian Assange) are currently living in embassies in various countries around the world. Typically, the person is being pursued by the host country, and the embassy's origin country is willing to offer refuge, but cannot get the person out of the country.

**But, if diplomatic law is respected, can an embassy send a person in a diplomatic pouch?**

In theory, an embassy could put a person in a box, label it a diplomatic pouch, and then send the box to a charter airport where it could be sent by government plane to the destination country, no?

Comment: [It's been tried, and didn't work out so great.](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/politics/umaru-dikko-the-man-who-was-nearly-spirited-away-in-a-diplomatic-bag-8061664.html)

Comment: @NateEldredge Haha I'm not talking about kidnapping, I'm talking about cases where the person living in the embassy would happily leave if he/she could